# Using a linked list as a char buffer for strings

Tags: performance, c, strings, array, linked-list

I've been getting into data structures in C lately, and I got the idea of making a char buffer which grows dinamically has you type by adding each character into a Linked List, and whose contents can be copied into a char array. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Here is the base structure of the LinkedList.
typedef struct linked_list_char {
    size_t size;                      //Number of characters (only known by the head)
    char item;                        //Character.
    struct linked_list_char* next;    //Next node.
} DavidLinkedListChar;

typedef DavidLinkedListChar* LinkedListChar; //This is how the head will be declared.

//Adds each node.
void addChar(LinkedListChar* head, char newItem) {
    LinkedListChar tracer = *head;    //This will go through the list.
    //If the head is NULL, the head will be accessed directly
    if(*head == NULL) {           
        *head = malloc(sizeof(DavidLinkedListChar));
        (*head)->item = newItem;
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        (*head)->size = 1;   //The size will be one.
    //If it isn't, the tracer will find the end of the list and insert a node.
    } else {
        while(tracer->next != NULL) tracer = tracer->next;
        tracer->next = malloc(sizeof(DavidLinkedListChar));
        tracer->next->item = newItem;
        tracer->next->next = NULL;
        (*head)->size++;    //The size will increase by one.
    }
    //I nullify all the pointers used, although I don't know if it is necessary.
    tracer = NULL;          
    head = NULL;
}

//Takes a char and allocates each character in the list, plus '\0'.
void convertIntoStaticString(char* destination, const LinkedListChar* source) {
    LinkedListChar tracer = *source;    //This will go through the list.
    int i = 0;                     //This will find the index in which '\0' needs to be.
    //This loop doesn't count the last member of the list, which is '\n'.
    while(tracer->next != NULL){
        destination[i] = tracer->item;
        tracer = tracer->next;
        i++;
    }
    destination[i] = '\0';     //Now the char array is null terminated.
    //Again: I don't know if this is necessary.
    tracer = NULL;
    destination = NULL;
}

//This function frees the entire list.
void deleteListChar(LinkedListChar* lChar) {
    LinkedListChar tracer = *lChar;     //This will go through the entire list
    LinkedListChar prev = NULL;         //This will contain the memory to be freed.
    //tracer will go down the list while every previous node pointed will be destroyed.
    while(tracer->next != NULL) {
        prev = tracer;
        tracer = tracer->next;
        free(prev);
        prev = NULL;
    }
    free(tracer);        //Frees the last node.
    free(*lChar);        //Frees the head (although it was probably freed already, but just in case it wasn't)
    //Nullifying everything.
    (*lChar) = NULL;
    lChar = NULL;
    tracer = NULL;
}

int main() {
   LinkedListChar cbuffer = NULL;
    char key = 'n';      
    //While the key isn't '\n', it will keep adding characters to the list.
    while(key != '\n') {
        key = fgetc(stdin);
        addChar(&cbuffer, key);
    }
    //Flexible char array of the same size as the buffer(counting the later ignored '\n' node).
    char name[cbuffer->size];
    //Copies the chars from the Linked List to the char array.
    convertIntoStaticString(name, &cbuffer);
    //Deletes the buffer.
    deleteListChar(&cbuffer);
    //Prints the char array.
    printf("%s", name);
    //Pauses until enter is pressed.
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work just fine; however I would like to know what more experienced programmers think of this. Plus, there's a considerable increase in memory for something like my fullname (which is 33 characters long, including blankspaces) of 20 KB, according to the Windows program manager. 
Do you guys think this was worth trying? Does my code contain any potential memory leak that might hinder performance? If one of you can try this code on the Linux Shell and tell me how well or badly it performed, it would be of great help!

Comment: What is the use case? You could use a linked list of buffers where each buffer contains several characters. This would reduce your overhead from one pointer pretty character to one per buffer. If there is one location where edits are happening, you can use a [gap buffer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer?wprov=sfla1) .

Comment: I'm still a noob at programming. I just wanted to try this out to see how it would performed, although I kind of guessed it wouldn't be ideal for most (if any) implementations. Thanks for the feedback! Next time I'll try coding better buffers. I just like trying out things for learning purporses.

Comment: That's a great way to learn!

Comment: Comments should explain why - not what or how, which should be evident in the code (noting that all general rules do have exceptions).  Most of your comments explain the what, which should be self-evident if the right variable and function names are chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like typedef like this:

```
typedef DavidLinkedListChar* LinkedListChar;
```

For that makes the code harder to read, specially when reviewing code from other
people. You overlook that line and the code does not make any sense.

```
//I nullify all the pointers used, although I don't know if it is necessary.
tracer = NULL;          
head = NULL;
```

Some people consider this good practice setting the freed pointers to `NULL`,
but in this case I personally don't see the point in `NULL`ing these two
pointers, you are not using them after these two instructions anyway, in fact
the function ends at that point. Setting these pointers can have some benefits
if later you want to check if they are still valid or not, but in this case I
don't see any benefit to that.

---

```
void convertIntoStaticString(char* destination, const LinkedListChar* source);
```

I don't see why you pass a pointer to `LinkedListChar` here, you are not
manipulating the contents of the list in any way. I'd declare this function as

```
void convertIntoStaticString(char* destination, const LinkedListChar source);
```

---

Your `deleteListChar` is almost correct:

```
//Frees the head (although it was probably freed already, but just in case it wasn't)
free(*lChar);
```

`*lChar` was indeed freed in the first iteration and because since then you
haven't change where `*lChar` is pointing to, you are doing a double free with
the same address, this is undefined behaviour. So remove that line. The
`(*lChar) = NULL;` line is OK, here I see a benefit of setting it to `NULL`.

---

One problem with your implementation is that you don't check the return values
of `malloc`, if it returns `NULL`, you cannot dereference the pointers. You
should alway check the return values of `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`.

And it's better practice to do the `malloc` like this:

```
int *arr = malloc(size * sizeof *arr);
```

I try to avoid `sizeof(<type>)` whenever possible, it's easy to make mistakes
(add a `*` too much for example) and it's easy to overlook when reviewing code.
On the other hand, using `sizeof *arr` will give you always the correct size
regardless of the type of `arr`, if you later change the type, then you don't
have to worry about the `sizeof` inside of functions that take the size of
objects as argument. So in this case I'd do:

```
*head = malloc(sizeof **head);
```

---

```
void convertIntoStaticString(char* destination, const LinkedListChar* source);
```

Here I also don't see why you pass a `LinkedListChar *source` instead of a
`LinkedListChar source`.

One bigger problem is that you don't take the size of the destination in
consideration, if the buffer is not large enough, you will overflow it.

Functions that take a pointer to a buffer should always take the length of the
buffer as argument as well, unless the end of the buffer is somehow encoded in
the values (like the `'\0'`-terminating byte for strings), but in this case this
function simple cannot know when to stop. So I'd rewrite this functions as:

```
int convertIntoStaticString(char *destination, size_t len, const LinkedListChar *source)
{
    if(destination == NULL || source == NULL || *source == NULL)
        return 0;

    LinkedListChar tracer = *source;    //This will go through the list.
    int i = 0;                     //This will find the index in which '\0' needs to be.

    // making sure not to overflow destination
    while(tracer->next != NULL && i < len - 1){
        destination[i] = tracer->item;
        tracer = tracer->next;
        i++;
    }

    destination[i] = '\0';     //Now the char array is null terminated.

    return 1;
}
```

and you would call it:

```
char name[1024];
convertIntoStaticString(name, sizeof name, &cbuffer);
```

or

```
char name[cbuffer->size+1];
convertIntoStaticString(name, sizeof name, &cbuffer);
```

This way your code is simply more robust.

---

What do I think about this implementation? As an exercise of linked lists, it's
OK, but I would not use that in production code, it has way to much overhead for
my taste when you can implement the same with a simple loop and one
`realloc` call:

```
#define BLOCKSIZE 64

char *get_line(FILE *fp)
{
    if(fp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *buffer = NULL, *tmp;
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    int c;

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        if(i == size)
        {
            tmp = realloc(buffer, size + BLOCKSIZE + 1);

            if(tmp == NULL)
            {
                // return all we've got so far
                if(buffer)
                    buffer[i] = 0;
                return buffer;
            }

            buffer = tmp;
            size += BLOCKSIZE; // do not count the + 1 for the
                               // 0-terminating byte, size should
                               // remain a multiple of BLOCKSIZE
        }

        buffer[i++] = c;
    }

    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        if(c != EOF)
        {
            return strdup(""); // user just pressed ENTER
        } else
            return NULL; // fp has no characters to be read
    }

    buffer[i] = 0;
    return buffer;
}
```

And if `strdup` is not available on your system

```
char *strdup(const char *txt)
{
    if(txt == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *tmp = calloc(strlen(txt), 1);

    if(tmp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return strcpy(tmp, txt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll use dynamic arrays next time. I understand now that having to allocate a node for each char is simply too expensive for any real use.